# Problem: Occasionally garbled letters and black windows (mostly after wake-up)

Tags: graphics, 16.04, hibernate, ubuntu-gnome

My first question, please be gentle ;-)

I have been using Ubuntu Gnome on my Laptop for 2 years now and I have always upgraded (currently 16.04 LTS) without problem.

For a while now, however, I frequently find that upon waking from hibernation, the screen is black, super key still works (in Gnome this shows an overview) and all other windows are black, too. Sometimes, moving around over icons makes them visible again, sometimes it doesn't.

Also, letters are either removed or garbled (replaced by random letters or digits), the two symptoms sometimes go hand in hand.

Restarting the Shell usually solves the problem, but it would be nice to prevent this from happening in the first place. On rare occassions, this also happens 'out of the blue', i.e. when I'm just working on the laptop, not after hibernation.

Any advice is appreciated!

Best,
Dominik

(PS: Wanted to post 3 screenshots but not enough reputation -.-)
[Black windows overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtSdR.png)

[Missing text in the overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzWXj.png)

[Black windows in general (possibly blocking an error message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foJHh.jpg)

Comment: Post the links in the comments, I'll add them.

Comment: Missing text in the overview (http://i.stack.imgur.com/UzWXj.png) and blacked out windows (potentially an error message) in non-overview mode (http://i.stack.imgur.com/foJHh.jpg) (I hope the links work)

Comment: Done, I've edited the post.

Comment: What graphics card?